# how to concatenate the result with the predefined string in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, string

I am new to Xcode, i am just trying to multiply the two numbers entered in the two textboxes on the button's click:

Below is my code for that:

```
label.text=  [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.3f", ([firstValue.text floatValue]) * ([secondvalue.text floatValue])];
```

Its displaying the result as its in label, but i want the out put is like **Result is: 23**
Please help me how can i do it?

Comment: Raman there are users who down vote randomly. For no reason. +1 from me.

Comment: @Rushi thanks but i just wanted to ask the man who downvotes what wrong is in the question??????

Comment: Even Im curious to know that. Generally when we downvote the question. Prompt comes which says Mention the comment. But users who don't have courage to mention it don't comment. SO must do something to stop this. I can see there's nothing wrong in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
label.text=  [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Result is: %.3f", ([firstValue.text floatValue]) * ([secondvalue.text floatValue])];
```

If you want only integer part as you mentioned in your question 23, then use `%.0f` or even `%d`

Comment: @anoop that i know i am learning it i studied that for float we need to use "f" and for integer "d"....

Answer (score 1):

```
label.text =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Result is %.3f", ([firstValue.text floatValue]) * ([secondvalue.text floatValue])];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%f`, so the result will be displayed in the form of floating point value.
Eg: **Result is : 23.00**

So you need to use `%d` instead of `%f`. Then the result will be: **Result is 23**

```
label.text=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result is: %d", ([firstValue.text floatValue] * [secondvalue.text floatValue])];
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever you want to display it has to be written in double quotes in format

```
label.text=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result is: %d", ([firstValue.text floatValue] * [secondvalue.text floatValue])];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `%d` for the `integer` values, and for `float` value you can use `%f`.